# Learning Python: Store values in dict from stdout

Tags: python

How can I do the following in Python:
I have a command output that outputs this:

```
Datexxxx
Clientxxx
Timexxx

Datexxxx
Client2xxx
Timexxx

Datexxxx
Client3xxx
Timexxx
```

And I want to work this in a dict like:

```
Client:(date,time), Client2:(date,time) ...
```

Comment: What did you come up with till now? If nothing: try reading something from _stdin_ and storing it in a variable and printing it to _stdout_.

Comment: a datetime.datetime is probably a better format to store the dates and times, although strptime isn't going to do anything useful with 'xxxx'; what does the actual format look like?

Comment: Please post the code that outputs that. It is important to know how it is currently working so that we can modify it to what you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After reading the data into a string `subject`, you could do this:

```
import re
d = {}
for match in re.finditer(
    """(?mx)
       ^Date(.*)\r?\n
       Client\d*(.*)\r?\n
       Time(.*)""", 
    subject):
        d[match.group(2)] = (match.group(1), match.group(2))
```

Comment: Thanks, i think it's what i need for now !

Answer (score 1):

What about using a dict with tuples?
Create a dictionary and add the entries:

```
dict = {}
dict['Client'] = ('date1','time1')
dict['Client2'] = ('date2','time2')
```

Accessing the entires:

```
dict['Client']
>>> ('date1','time1')
```

Comment: Ah ok. I misunderstood your question.

Answer (score 1):

How about something like:

```
rows = {}
thisrow = []

for line in output.split('\n'):
        if line[:4].lower() == 'date':
                thisrow.append(line)
        elif line[:6].lower() == 'client':
                thisrow.append(line)
        elif line[:4].lower() == 'time':
                thisrow.append(line)
        elif line.strip() == '':
                rows[thisrow[1]] = (thisrow[0], thisrow[2])
                thisrow = []

print rows
```

Assumes a trailing newline, no spaces before lines, etc.